# Не работает сайт на java

Tags: java, html, servlet, jar

Видимо, я чего-то не понимаю...

Я написал backend на Java, и несколько страниц (HTML, JS).

В `pom.xml` файле добавил зависимость на spring-boot-starter-jetty.

При запуске web-приложения в IntelliJ Idea всё работает, захожу на адрес `localhost:8888`, открывается `index.html` и так далее.

После этого собираю jar-файл с помощью maven. Запускаю этот файл из cmd (`java -jar filename.jar`). Захожу на `localhost:8888` или на `localhost:8888/index.html`, и ничего не открывается. При этом на прямой get запрос (`localhost:8888/person/1`) ответ приходит (у меня в виде JSON).

В интернете нашёл такую конфигурацию, но не помогает:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/public</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: там наверно нет страниц

Comment: В jar-файле? Есть. Name.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/public и дальше мои файлы html.

Comment: покажите структуру директорий и чем вы собираете jar-файл.

Comment: Сборка maven.  
![jar 1](https://ibb.co/iGy2Yy),

![jar 2](https://ibb.co/jco2Yy),

![jar 3](https://ibb.co/d9s70d),

![jar 4](https://ibb.co/iR0ufd).

Comment: покажите код который нужен для этого

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Код, который нужен... для чего?

Comment: я не понял вопрос, страницы не открываются, что это значит?

Comment: Я запускаю jar-файл, захожу на адрес (у меня) localhost:8888. Должен открыться index.html. Но нет, Whitelabel Error Page.
Через ide всё работает.

Comment: Сформулируй вопрос правильно, вытягивать из тебя по нитке проблему тяжело.

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Может, так будет понятней.

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar):

> To create an executable jar, we need to add the spring-boot-maven-plugin to our pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

В результате pom.xml для простого Spring Boot приложения будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Из той же [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content):

> Do not use the src/main/webapp directory if your application is packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it works only with war packaging, and it is silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.
>
> Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources)

**Папка webapp используется при упаковке в war-файл**. Используя Spring Boot Вы упаковываете Ваше веб-приложение в jar-файл, следовательно, папки webapp у Вас быть не должно. **Помещайте Ваши страницы html в папку resourses/static**.

Comment: В этой конфигурации в итоговый jar файл не попадает папка webapp с моими html-страницами.

Comment: Или папка со страницами должна быть где-то рядом? Не в jar-файле.

Comment: И в самом деле. Положил jar-файл рядом с папкой webapp, и всё заработало. И не нужно закидывать webapp в jar-ник.
Буду дальше разбираться с тонкостями web-приложений.

Comment: @Bakhuss я дополнил ответ. Думаю теперь будет понятнее.

Comment: @Bakhuss _В этой конфигурации в итоговый jar файл не попадает папка webapp с моими html-страницами_ - так и должно быть. "Maven рассматривает" папку webapp только при создании war-файла.